# Global navigation depth with Sharepoint Server Publishing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Am in the process of setting Sharepoint 2013. We had our global navigation set up and working nicely then enabled SharePoint Server Publishing so the our theme could be inherited by all the subsites but the global navigation now seems to be limited to just 2 levels deep.

Is there anyway to restore the navigation without turning off the Sharepoint Server Publishing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing through code under global navigation setting.....

```
   StaticDisplayLevels="3"
   DynamicDisplayLevels="3"
```